# Xamarin Android : Hide/Unhide App From App Launcher

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am Creating an Locker App which Locks Media But by Providing other securities i want the app to hide from the app launcher section so it can be invisible to the non-authorized users.
is there anyway to hide app from the launcher, and again Un-hide it and make it visible when user want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to Hide App From launcher.

```
    public void hide()
    { 
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)).Name);
        PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, ComponentEnabledState.Disabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);
    }
```

And This to Unhide the App.

```
    public void unhide()
    { 
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)).Name);
        PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, ComponentEnabledState.Enabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);
    }
```

**(Xamarin Version Code)**